# Why I am getting Column Name Missing error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I wrote a SP which will call internally another parameterized SP and output will be store into a physical table.While I am executing Outer  SP  I am  getting following error.

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CBs_LargeExposer, Line 88 [Batch
>   Start Line 12] Invalid column name 'SlNo'.

I observed, if I execute inner SP in separate window  and very  next to it if I execute the same outer SP is working fine, after certain time if I execute the same statement(Outer SP) I am getting same error.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CBS_GlMapping]
@finYear nvarchar(30)='2019-2020',
@quarter char(5)='Q2',
@Oflag Varchar(6)='O4'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Declare @QtrStart date,@QtrSEnd date,@FyFrom int,@FyTo int,@BranchId int 

    select @FyFrom=year(YearBeginDate),@FyTo=Year(YEarEndDate) from BranchTable where BranchCode in(select OrgBankCode from OrgDetails) 

    IF(@FyFrom < left(@finYear,4) and @FyTo < Right(@finYear,4))
    Begin
        print 'Sorry, Recods are not available for the financial year ' + @finYear
        return
    End
    If(@quarter='Q1')
    Begin
        select @QtrStart=YearBeginDate,@QtrSEnd=EOMONTH(DATEADD(MM,2,YearBeginDate)) from BranchTable where BranchCode in(select OrgBankCode from OrgDetails) 
    End
    If(@quarter='Q2')
    Begin
        select @QtrStart=Dateadd(mm,3,YearBeginDate),@QtrSEnd=EOMONTH(DATEADD(MM,5,YearBeginDate)) from BranchTable where BranchCode in(select OrgBankCode from OrgDetails) 
    End
    If(@quarter='Q3')
    Begin
        select @QtrStart=Dateadd(mm,6,YearBeginDate),@QtrSEnd=EOMONTH(DATEADD(MM,8,YearBeginDate)) from BranchTable where BranchCode in(select OrgBankCode from OrgDetails) 
    End
    If(@quarter='Q4')
    Begin
        select @QtrStart=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,Dateadd(mm,-2,YEarEndDate)), 0),@QtrSEnd=YEarEndDate from BranchTable where BranchCode in(select OrgBankCode from OrgDetails) 
        End
    /* To handel the Financial year */
    if(left(@finYear,4)<year(@QtrStart) and @quarter<>'Q4')
    begin
        set @QtrStart = cast(left(@finYear,4) as varchar(4))+'-'+cast(month(@QtrStart) as Varchar(2))+'-'+Cast(day(@QtrStart) as Varchar(2))
        set @QtrSEnd = cast(left(@finYear,4) as varchar(4))+'-'+cast(month(@QtrSEnd) as Varchar(2))+'-'+Cast(day(@QtrSEnd) as Varchar(2))
    end
    if(right(@finYear,4)<year(@QtrStart) and @quarter='Q4')
    begin
        set @QtrStart = cast(right(@finYear,4) as varchar(4))+'-'+cast(month(@QtrStart) as Varchar(2))+'-'+Cast(day(@QtrStart) as Varchar(2))
        set @QtrSEnd = cast(right(@finYear,4) as varchar(4))+'-'+cast(month(@QtrSEnd) as Varchar(2))+'-'+Cast(day(@QtrSEnd) as Varchar(2))
    end
    Create table #tempData
    (
        Bal numeric(15,2)
    )

    declare @sql varchar(500),@sql2 varchar(500),@day Varchar(10),@Month varchar(2),@Year varchar(4)
    select @day= Day(@QtrSEnd)
    select @Month= month(@QtrSEnd)
    select @Year= Year(@QtrSEnd)
    Create table #temp
    (   slno int,
        glcode Varchar(500),
        GlLen int,
        ColNO varchar(50),
        CellNo varchar(50),
        Amount Numeric(15,2)
    )

    declare @tsql varchar(500)
    set @tsql=N'
    insert into #temp 
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by glcode) slno,glcode,LEN(Glcode) GlLen,ColNo,CellNo,amount 
    from BsGl'+@Oflag+'
    where glcode <>'''' '
    exec(@tsql)

    declare @LoopStart int,@loopEnd Int,@glcode varchar(500),@amt numeric(15,0)
    select @LoopStart=Min(Slno) from #temp
    select @loopEnd=MAX(Slno) from #temp

    while (@LoopStart <= @loopEnd)
    begin

        select @glcode= Glcode from #temp where slno = @LoopStart

        set @sql='insert into #tempData select Sum(day'+@day+') from DayBal where AcYear='+@Year+' and acmonth='+@Month+'and GlCode in(SELECT glcode FROM dbo.splitstring(convert(varchar(500),'''+@glcode+''')))' 
        EXEC(@sql)
        update #temp set Amount=(select Bal from #tempData) where slno =@LoopStart

        set @LoopStart=@LoopStart+1
        Truncate table #tempData
    end
    set @tsql=''
    set @tsql='update BsGl'+@Oflag+' set Amount=0.00 where Glcode ='''' '
    EXEC(@tsql)
    set @tsql=''
    set @tsql='update B set B.amount=isnull(round((Case when A.Amount<0 then A.Amount*(-1) else A.Amount end/1000),0),0) from #temp a inner join BsGl'+@Oflag+' B on a.CellNo=B.CellNo  and B.ColNo=A.ColNo'
    EXEC(@tsql)
    IF(@Oflag='O4')
    BEGIN
        EXEC [DBO].[CBs_LargeExposer] @QtrSEnd
    END
    Drop table #temp
End
```

Comment: Pondering that `#temp` might not be a very unique table name. Could you be running something else that creates a different `#temp` that doesn't have the same columns?

Comment: You should try select * from #temp in your procedure to ensure it has slno column. also, check your database is not case sensitive

Comment: drop your #temp table and run again.   The definitions may not be in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution for the error. I created same #temporary table in outer sp as well as in inner sp with different columns. Basically a #temporary table's scope is limited to the session but when you are calling a inner Sp inside a outer sp it will consider a single session.

Outer SP TempTable Declaration

```
Create table #tempData
    (
        Bal numeric(15,2)
    )
```

Inner SP TempTable Declaration

```
CREATE TABLE #tempData(
    [ID] int  identity(1,1) ,
    [Funded] [numeric](15, 2) NOT NULL,
    [NonFunded] [numeric](2, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Limitsanctioned] [numeric](15, 2) NOT NULL
    )
```

So I changed the #tmpData to #tempData1 in outer Sp it's working fine.

Comment: Tip: Use a more meaningful name, e.g. `#MonthBalanceSummary`. It makes the code more readable and reduces the chance of a name collision.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have tried this already. Try specifying the exact same column name "slno" as in CREATE TABLE statement, in the below two SELECT statements, instead of "Slno".

```
select @LoopStart=Min(Slno) from #temp
select @loopEnd=MAX(Slno) from #temp
```